# Select the year that September is in from a date range

Tags: mysql

I have a table of start dates and end dates - mostly a full year but starting at any month.

I want to get a report of counts of those rows that were active in the current month of each year. It'll be like count - current, count last year, count 2 years ago etc

I build my query in PHP so I can easily use sum(case when then end) and hard code in the dates or sum of a subquery but I figure there may be a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: `group by year(datefield), month(datefield) where month(datefield)=$month_you_want`?

Comment: I have two dates - and the date I'm checking on is unlikely to be either the start or the end. This month is September the year that a row was active in September.

Ex: 1 Nov 2010 - 31 Oct 2011 would return 2011
Ex: 1 Aug 2010 - 31 Jul 2011 would return 2010

Comment: I think I'm going to run with this
`CASE  WHEN MONTH(enddate) < MONTH(NOW()) THEN YEAR(enddate)-1 ELSE YEAR(enddate) END AS yeargroup`
    There could be a gotcha when there are short date spans so I'll need to factor that in too.

Comment: and further simplified to `YEAR(enddate) - IF( MONTH(enddate) < MONTH(NOW()), 1, 0)` but still without a check on startdate...

Answer (score 2):

You could use expressions rather than "hard code in the dates"

To return the first date of the current month, you could use an expression that returns the year and month of the current date, and substitute in a fixed value for the first of the month, like this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01')
```

To get a year before that

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

For a range comparison, to check if there's "overlap" (of the period between `start_date` and `end_date` of each row in the table), and the first and last day in a given month, I would do something like this:

```
     end_date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01')
AND start_date < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

This pattern (greater than or equal to the first of month and less than the first of the next month) works for dates as well as datetime that includes a time component. (This check assumes that a NULL value for end_date isn't being used to represent "no end date"... the check would need to be adjusted to accommodate that.)

If I had the specification (as I interpret it), I'd probably do it something like this:

```
 SELECT SUM( t.start_date   < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL   1 MONTH
         AND t.end_date    >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL   0 MONTH
        ) AS `count_current_year`

      , SUM( t.start_date   < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -11 MONTH
         AND t.end_date    >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -12 MONTH
        ) AS `count_previous_year`

      , SUM( t.start_date   < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -23 MONTH
         AND t.end_date    >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -24 MONTH
        ) AS `count_two_years_ago`

  FROM mytable t
```

I don't know that this is any better. (It's probably a lot uglier than what you have, but I don't think there's anything in there that's cruft.)

I don't see a way to make effective use of an index on `start_date` or `end_date` (given a row represents a "date range") unless the query can be satisfied entirely from an index (i.e. a covering index exists.)

Comment: @SarahKing: the "trick" there is that MySQL evaluates a boolean expression as 1 (for true), 0 (for false) or NULL (for NULL). That's just shorthand that eliminates the need for an `IF()` function or a more tedious (but standard) `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you can retrieve the first day of the month in which any `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` item occurs with this string.

```
 DATE(DATE_FORMAT(when, '%Y-%m-01'))
```

This little function is tremendously useful in `GROUP BY` expressions and the like.

Comment: I use that little gem a lot. Thanks for your answer Ollie.